# Can I plug both laptop and multi-fx to audio interface which is connected to a speaker?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, audio

Looking to output my multi fx to my speaker but also at the same time output my laptop to the speaker. So setup is looking like:

Guitar -> Multi FX -> Focusrite Scarlett

Laptop -> Focusrite Scarlett

Focusrite Scarlet -> Speaker

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want to connect the laptop using USB cable? It seems like this is exactly how it's supposed to be used, though you'd better check the user manual to make sure.

There is a potential of ground loop cause mains connections of the multi FX and the laptop, resulting in noise. If it happens, it can be solved or improved by connecting the multi FX to the XLR input and using ground lift, if available, or disconnecting the laptop from the power (though that might be quite inconvenient).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I simply want to output my guitarfx and my laptop through the same speaker so I can play backing track at the same time for instance.

Comment: @elroikendo as mentioned in the answer, this is precisely what the interface is designed to to be used for. Plug the audio interface into your laptop via usb, chose it under sound devices (or similar, check the manual!) and verify the laptop plays back through your speakers. Then go ahead and plug the guitar fx into the front of the scareltt. Either get the guitar audio to the speakers by using the blend/mix knob on the front (direct) or route it via some audio software running on the computer (where you can further process/record etc).

Comment: Bless you good sir. Thanks for your kind answer, I am just worried that the thing may have weird latency cuz even abit of latency screws up electric guitar. Thanks!

Comment: @elroikendo no problem! It may have a bit of latency when first plugged in, but latency is something that can be set on any software DAW you may use (cubase, reaper etc). You increase or decrease latency (buffer) depending on your needs. For just playing along to a backing track from your computer, with your guitar going direct to the speakers it shouldn’t be a problem you encounter. Your Scarlett should have a large knob labelled ‘monitor’, with that set all the way one way or the other it sends anything plugged into the front inputs directly to speakers with no latency to worry about.

Comment: @elroikendo Just try! You might encounter problems you didn't think of, but also realize that what you thought would be problems are not.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you really want a mixer, but for mixing the backing track and the multi FX the Scarlett can do the job too. The setup is to direct the output of the laptop to the audio interface, plug the multi FX to Scarlett's input and turn on direct monitoring. No software on the laptop needed, no additional latency involved. The advice about ground loop applies.